# Регулярное выражение: 4 цифры и одна буква

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как будет выглядеть регулярное выражение, которое ищет 4 цифры и одну букву в строке?

Comment: А сами что-нибудь пробовали?

Comment: В каком порядке идут цифры и буква? Вперемешку или последовательно?

Comment: @Vesper, Cначала цифры, потом одна буква

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]/`.

Вначале блок, который ищет символы "[0-9]", т.е. цифры, который должен встретиться {4} раза, потом блок "[A-Za-z]", т.е. буква.

Comment: А как насчёт русских букв? А если будет `1253565sfhjk`?

Comment: @stribizhev, русские буквы не нужны.

Comment: @stribizhev Вот начинается - буквы не те, цифры не те :) Буквы дорисовываешь в скобки к буквам. А если будет `1253565sfhjk` все равно будет true, так как разговор о начале и конце строки в ТЗ не стоял, но совпадение будет `3565s`.

Comment: Да, но ведь и [`1d`](https://regex101.com/r/jF2mK4/1) тоже найдёт.

Comment: Мда, почему-то прочел как "от одной до 4 цифр" и одна буква. Тогда `/[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]/`.